# How to stop a Service running in a separate(private) process in Android?

Tags: android

Normally we can stop a Service by `Context.stopService(new Intent(...))`, but is that the case for a Service in a separate process? I was debugging for that scenario and didn't see the Service is destroyed after that call.

Comment: are you tring to stop the service from the activity or stop the service in another service ?

Answer (score 0):

use stopSelf(); method to stop the service after completing the task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can stop a service with that line of code however it would not happen instantly and depends on OS.